# validation list - can't refrence a range in another sheet in "formula1" as a variable

Tags: vba, excel

```
   Set AcctRng = Sheets("New Accounts").Range(Cells(2, 1),Cells(countnonblank1 + 1, 1))
   CntNBlnk = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(AcctRng)

   Set MasterSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data")
   LstRo = MasterSht.Cells(MasterSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

 '  Sheets("New Accounts").Range("a5") = LstRo

   Set ChoiceRng = Sheets("Master Data").Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(LstRo, 1))
   'Sheets("Master Data").Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(LstRo, 1))


 '  Choice = "ChoiceRange"


     Sheets("New Accounts").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(CntNBlnk + 1, 2)).Select
     With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
   .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
     xlBetween, Formula1:=ChoiceRng
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

all the variables are declared accordingly, is there some referencing problem with the formula1 part in the validation list code??

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: the version is excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

> , is there some refrencing problem with the formula1 part in the validation list code??

Yes: `ChoiceRng` is an object. Use the `.Address` property explicitly:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
     AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop,  _
     Operator:=xlBetween, _
     Formula1:=ChoiceRng.Address
```